# How to disable NSURLSession WebSocket for WKWebView by cordova

Tags: cordova

I have a web application using signalr (websocket) which is packaged to the iOS app by cordova, on iOS 14, the iOS app works well, but on iOS 15, the websocket can't be connected. I know the issue is something relevant to NSURLSession Websocket, because I can open my web application in Safari by following the below steps:

Open the Settings app
Scroll down and tap on “Safari”
Scroll down to the bottom and tap on “Advanced”
Tap on “Experimental Features” at the bottom
Scroll down until you see “NSURLSession WebSocket”
Disable “NSURLSession WebSocket”

But the above setting doesn't take effective for the iOS app, do you know how to do the similar  thing for WKWebView by cordova?

Comment: Not sure but could be helpful:


iOS 17 update
Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Experimental Features -> NSURLSession WebSocket is no longer available as a toggle, and appears to be set to on all the time.